# After program abnormal exit, command is not echoed and new line doesn't work in bash output

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, printing

Like the title, I have seen case where after a program is abnormally finished (because of bug I made usually), the shell doesn't echo my command anymore including the new-line (but I can see it accepts and runs it) so whatevery I type-in, it just prints everything in a single line without new-line. For example if I keep pressing enter key, the prompt string is printed to the right like this.

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/ProjectS/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/test$ ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/ProjectS/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/test$ ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/ProjectS/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/test$ ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/ProjectS/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/test$ ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/ProjectS/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/test$ ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/ProjectS/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/test$
```

Very annoying.. I have no choice but to exit the shell and open a new tab(which opens a new shell). In this abnormal situation, is there any method I can revive the shell behavior without openning a new shell?

Comment: you can reset your terminal with `reset`

Comment: @bac0n Wow that works! Thank you! Please make rewrite your comment as an answer. I'll select it.